# FXML BorderPane size not changing despite using setMinSize() and setPrefSize() in JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, dependency-injection, fxml

I'm facing an issue where the size of my `BorderPane` in an FXML file (`mainLayoutBorderPane`) is not changing, remaining at (0,0), despite attempting to set it using `setMinSize()` or `setPrefSize()` in a custom hook `styleSetup()` I wrote (I expect it to execute after my controller initialization).

I think I'm misunderstanding some concepts about the lifetime of scenes and controllers in JavaFX, or I might have made a mistake in the FXML code. Let me explain my problem.

This is the entry point of my app, where I set the admin login page as the starting scene with a `SceneManager`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        stage.setWidth(AppConfig.LOGIN_STAGE_WIDTH);
        stage.setHeight(AppConfig.LOGIN_STAGE_HEIGHT);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        SceneManager sceneManager = new SceneManager(stage);
        sceneManager.setSpringContext(springContext);
        sceneManager.switchingScene("/dev/bananaback/fxml/admin_login_page.fxml");
        sceneManager.showRootStage();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

I use a `SceneManager` to support switching scenes in my JavaFX application, which involves holding the root stage and a hash map of scenes. To integrate Spring dependency injection (DI) into my code, I made some modifications based on an answer I found on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52932422/10283956). These modifications include writing a `setSpringContext()` method to retrieve the `springContext` for the `loader.setControllerFactory()` method.

Despite implementing these changes, I'm encountering issues with the size of a `BorderPane` in one of my FXML files (`mainLayoutBorderPane`). Despite setting its size using `setMinSize()` or `setPrefSize()` within a custom hook method `styleSetup()`, the size remains at (0,0).

I suspect there might be misunderstandings regarding the lifecycle of scenes and controllers in JavaFX, or I may have made mistakes in the FXML code. Let me elaborate on my problem.

At the entry point of my application, I set the admin login page as the starting scene using the `SceneManager`. Here's how I've structured my code:

```
public class SceneManager {
    private final Stage rootStage;
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    public SceneManager(Stage rootStage) {
        if (rootStage == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.rootStage = rootStage;
    }

    public void setSpringContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext) {
        this.springContext = springContext;
    }

    private final Map<String, Scene> scenes = new HashMap<>();

    public void switchingScene(String url) {
        Scene scene = scenes.computeIfAbsent(url, u -> {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(u));
            loader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
            try {
                Pane p = loader.load();
                BaseController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.setSceneManager(this);
                controller.styleSetup();
                return new Scene(p);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });
        rootStage.setScene(scene);
    }

    public void setStageSize(double x, double y) {
        rootStage.setWidth(x);
        rootStage.setHeight(y);
        rootStage.centerOnScreen();
    }

    public void showRootStage() {
        this.rootStage.show();
    }

    public void closeStage() {
        this.rootStage.close();
    }
}
```

My admin_login_page.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<HBox
    fx:id="containerHBox"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    fx:controller="dev.bananaback.controllers.LoginController"
    stylesheets="@../css/admin_login_page.css">

    <!-- Left panel containing login form -->
    <VBox fx:id="leftPanelVBox" styleClass="left-panel">
        <StackPane fx:id="leftPanelPane">
            <Label fx:id="smallTitle" text="Sign in to dashboard" styleClass="title"/>
            <Label fx:id="phoneNumberLabel" text="Phone number" styleClass="field-title"/>
            <TextField fx:id="phoneNumberField" promptText="Type your phone number" styleClass="input-field"/>
            <Label fx:id="passwordLabel" text="Password" styleClass="field-title"/>
            <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" promptText="Password" styleClass="input-field"/>
            <Button fx:id="loginButton" text="Login" styleClass="rounded-button" onAction="#loginUser"/>
            <Label fx:id="errorMessageLabel" styleClass="error"/>
        </StackPane>
    </VBox>

    <!-- Right panel containing big text -->
    <VBox fx:id="rightPanelVBox" styleClass="right-panel">
        <StackPane fx:id="rightPanelPane">
            <Label fx:id="welcomeLabel" text="Take their money :)" styleClass="welcome"/>
            <Label fx:id="smallWelcomeLabel" text="Empty their wallet!" styleClass="welcome-small"/>
        </StackPane>
    </VBox>
</HBox>
```

I use `fx:controller` to specify which controller associated with that fxml. The elements in this fxml is just the structure, all the sizes and locations is set in the controller.

```
package dev.bananaback.controllers;
// ... import statements

@Component
public class LoginController extends BaseController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private VBox leftPanelVBox;

    @FXML
    private VBox rightPanelVBox;

    @FXML
    private HBox containerHBox;

    @FXML
    private Label smallTitle;

    @FXML
    private StackPane leftPanelPane;

    @FXML
    private StackPane rightPanelPane;

    @FXML
    private TextField phoneNumberField;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;

    @FXML
    private Label phoneNumberLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label passwordLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label welcomeLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label smallWelcomeLabel;

    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private void loginUser() throws IOException {
        // sceneManager.closeStage();
        sceneManager.switchingScene("/dev/bananaback/fxml/main_layout.fxml");
    }

    public LoginController() {
        System.out.println("Login controller constructed");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        System.out.println("Login controller initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void styleSetup() {
        double halfWidth = AppConfig.LOGIN_STAGE_WIDTH / 2.0;
        leftPanelVBox.setPrefWidth(halfWidth);
        rightPanelVBox.setPrefWidth(halfWidth);

        leftPanelPane.setPrefWidth(halfWidth);
        leftPanelPane.setPrefHeight(AppConfig.LOGIN_STAGE_HEIGHT);
        leftPanelPane.setLayoutX(0);
        leftPanelPane.setLayoutY(0);

        rightPanelPane.setPrefWidth(halfWidth);
        rightPanelPane.setPrefHeight(AppConfig.LOGIN_STAGE_HEIGHT);
        rightPanelPane.setLayoutX(halfWidth);
        rightPanelPane.setLayoutY(0);

        smallTitle.setTranslateX(0);
        smallTitle.setTranslateY(-(AppConfig.LOGIN_STAGE_HEIGHT / 2 - 145));

        phoneNumberLabel.setTranslateX(-100);
        phoneNumberLabel.setTranslateY(-80);

        passwordLabel.setTranslateX(-115);
        passwordLabel.setTranslateY(-10);

        phoneNumberField.setPrefWidth(280);
        phoneNumberField.setMaxWidth(280);
        phoneNumberField.setPrefHeight(35);
        phoneNumberField.setTranslateX(0);
        phoneNumberField.setTranslateY(-50);

        passwordField.setPrefWidth(280);
        passwordField.setMaxWidth(280);
        passwordField.setPrefHeight(35);
        passwordField.setTranslateX(0);
        passwordField.setTranslateY(20);

        loginButton.setTranslateX(0);
        loginButton.setTranslateY(80);

        welcomeLabel.setTranslateX(0);
        welcomeLabel.setTranslateY(-30);

        smallWelcomeLabel.setTranslateX(-100);
        smallWelcomeLabel.setTranslateY(10);

        System.out.println("Login controlle style set");

    }

}
```

All of my controllers extends this `BaseController`:

```
public abstract class BaseController {
    protected SceneManager sceneManager;

    public void setSceneManager(SceneManager sceneManager) {
        this.sceneManager = sceneManager;
    }

    public abstract void styleSetup();
}
```

I add an abstract method `styleSetup()` to call it after retrieving the controller in `SceneManager` swtich scene method:

```
public void switchingScene(String url) {
        Scene scene = scenes.computeIfAbsent(url, u -> {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(u));
            loader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
            try {
                Pane p = loader.load();
                BaseController controller = loader.getController();
                controller.setSceneManager(this);
                controller.styleSetup(); // <----- 
                return new Scene(p);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });
        rootStage.setScene(scene);
    }
```

And for this login view, everything works well as I expected. The style of the FXML is set successfully in the `styleSetup()` method of the controller. However, the problem arises when I attempt to switch to the main layout view from the `LoginController`, where the main layout consists of a `BorderPane` containing a navigation bar on the top and the rest being the main content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="dev.bananaback.controllers.MainLayoutController"
            fx:id="mainLayoutBorderPane">

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <VBox id="navBar" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT">
        <fx:include source="nav_bar.fxml" />
    </VBox>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <VBox id="mainContent" BorderPane.alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT">
        <fx:include source="main_content.fxml" />
    </VBox>
    
</BorderPane>
```

The style is messed up after switching to the main layout view. Upon investigation, I discovered that the `BorderPane` size is 0. To address this issue, I attempted to change the size in my `MainLayoutController`'s `styleSetup()` method:

```
package dev.bananaback.controllers;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import dev.bananaback.AppConfig;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

@Component
public class MainLayoutController extends BaseController implements Initializable {
    private MainContentController mainContentController;
    private NavBarController navBarController;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane mainLayoutBorderPane;

    public MainLayoutController() {
        System.out.println("Main layout controller constructed");

    }

    @Autowired
    public MainLayoutController(MainContentController mainContentController, NavBarController navBarController) {
        this.mainContentController = mainContentController;
        this.navBarController = navBarController;
        System.out.println("Main layout controller constructed");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        navBarController.sayHello();
        System.out.println("Main layout controller initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void styleSetup() {

        mainLayoutBorderPane.setMinSize(AppConfig.MAIN_STAGE_WIDTH,
                AppConfig.MAIN_STAGE_HEIGHT - AppConfig.MAIN_STAGE_NAV_BAR_HEIGHT);
        mainLayoutBorderPane.setPrefSize(AppConfig.MAIN_STAGE_WIDTH,
                AppConfig.MAIN_STAGE_HEIGHT - AppConfig.MAIN_STAGE_NAV_BAR_HEIGHT);

        System.out.println(mainLayoutBorderPane.getWidth());
        System.out.println(mainLayoutBorderPane.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Main layout controller style set");

    }
}
```

I expected the `BorderPane` size to change after setting it in the `styleSetup()` method of `MainLayoutController`, but it remains unchanged. Upon further investigation, I attempted to print some debugging information, and here are the results:

```
2024-03-21T12:33:02.374+07:00  INFO 20668 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application using Java 17.0.8 with PID 20668 (started by LENOVO in d:\Java_related\complexscene)
2024-03-21T12:33:02.379+07:00  INFO 20668 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
Login controller constructed <---
Main layout controller constructed <---
2024-03-21T12:33:03.094+07:00  INFO 20668 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 1.111 seconds (process running for 1.837)
Login controller initialized <---
Login controlle style set <---
Hello world! <---
Main layout controller initialized <---
0.0
0.0
Main layout controller style set <---
```

The size of the border pane is still 0. I've observed that the style set method is called after the controller is initialized. Additionally, I've printed something in the constructor and noticed that only one instance of `MainLayoutController` is created. However, I don't know what mistake I've made here. Please help me fix this. You can find my code at the following GitHub repository: [SO-JavaFX-help_request](https://github.com/bananaback/SO-JavaFX-help_request). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I haven't studied your code in depth, but one issue is that you are defining the children of the `BorderPane` incorrectly. In the FXML file, you have both the "navigation bar" and the "main content" *directly* nested in the border pane element. If this were in code, that's the same as doing `bp.getChildren().add(navBar)`. But that's not right. You need to do, e.g., `bp.setTop(navBar)` instead. In FXML, you would do that by nesting the navigation bar in a `<top>` element. Similar for "center" (which I assume is where you want the main content to go).

Comment: As for seeing the width and height as `0` when you print them out, I think you're just querying the values too early. You call `styleSetup()` before the root layout has even added to a scene. There simply hasn't been a layout pass yet, so none of the nodes have been resized/repositioned.

Comment: Related: [generating a layout pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I just edited the fxml file, wrapped the two child components in <top> and <center> tags, everything displays as I want, divided into two parts for navbar and main content. But it seems that is the default ratio, I tried changing the size of the border pane to 0 or changing the size of the window, the result is a navbar on top and the remaining main content fills the screen. That makes me sure that the changes in the MainLayoutController's styleSetup() function are not being implemented.

Comment: I wonder why LoginController also has a styleSetup() function but the changes are applied, I tried commenting all the commands inside LoginController's styleSetup(), the interface becomes chaotic. That makes me think that LoginController's styleSetup() might actually help.

Comment: Off topic, but you your layout choices are quite strange.  A StackPane is for stacking stuff, not laying out fields in a login form.  And FXML in general is for creating layouts.  It is strange to just define the fields in FXML, but then do the actual layout with coded absolute coordinates.  Also, layout is generally done by configuring layoutX/Y values (or more likely letting a layout pane set those values for you) and not by using translation (which is often used for animation).  You would probably be better off utilizing appropriate layout panes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out to me. I also think StackPane is not a good choice. But it was my final choice after struggling with other layouts for a while. Because my ability to use FXML is terrible and I use a programmatically solution instead to meet the deadline first. I tried searching for some tutorials online and found that most tutorials use java code instead of FXML.

Comment: FXML is really built to be (mainly) created and edited using SceneBuilder.  I didn't try it, but I am guessing that if you loaded your FXML into SceneBuilder it would just be a mess of overlapping nodes.  I suggest that instead, you load the FXML into SceneBuilder, and modify the layout panes and (if needed) a few sizing hints for nodes.  Use the preview function in SceneBuilder to make sure the FXML generated nodes work fine when you resize them.  Remove all (or at least most) of the size hardcoding in your code, then reintegrate into your code to get the display you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257223/discussion-between-poor-noob-at-code-and-jewelsea).

Comment: Read the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm) on layout panes to see how they work. That is quite old and using Java, not FXML, but nothing much has changed in the layout API and the principles apply whether you are using the API via Java or via FXML. Hardcoding layouts is simply not the way the API is intended to be used (and for good reason, IMHO); the idea is you should choose layout panes whose strategy matches your requirements and let them implement the strategy directly.